# Android Studio not starting in Windows 10: Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

Tags: android-studio, windows-10, runtimeexception, illegalargumentexception

I have installed Android Studio successfully.But when I start it,it starts fetching SDK components and in the midway the following error pops
java.lang.Runtime Exception:IllegalArgumentException.I am using Windows 10 operating system.

The Following is the complete description of the error

```
Internal error. Please report to https://code.google.com/p/android/issues

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform.<init> must not be null
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:178)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1$1$1.run(MainImpl.java:52)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:362)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument for @NotNull parameter 'name' of com/android/tools/idea/welcome/Platform.<init> must not be null
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.<init>(Platform.java)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.getLatestPlatform(Platform.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.Platform.createSubtree(Platform.java:89)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.createComponentTree(InstallComponentsPath.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.InstallComponentsPath.init(InstallComponentsPath.java:215)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizardPath.attachToWizard(DynamicWizardPath.java:97)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard.addPath(DynamicWizard.java:233)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizard.init(FirstRunWizard.java:75)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.setupWizard(FirstRunWizardHost.java:100)
    at com.android.tools.idea.welcome.FirstRunWizardHost.getWelcomePanel(FirstRunWizardHost.java:92)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.<init>(WelcomeFrame.java:68)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.welcomeScreen.WelcomeFrame.showNow(WelcomeFrame.java:173)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication$IdeStarter.main(IdeaApplication.java:302)
    at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:172)
    ... 16 more
```

Comment: do what it advises you. go to the page, look if such an error post was already reported and vote for it or create a new bug if you can't find a bug item.

Answer (score 6):

Open file path :
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin\idea.properties
 add "disable.android.first.run=true"

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same error.  My fix was ugly but it worked.

Running the 'bundled' install wasn't happy on my win10 and I got your exact error message.

Basically android studio sdk manager had strewn the android sdk across various directories under c:\users\jhealy\appdata including sdk1 and sdk2 and some others.

I uninstalled all android sdk and studio stuff.  I manually purged the directories.

I then installed, using the standalone sdk installer, the android sdk into c:\android.

I then installed the NO TOOLS version of Android Studio - android-studio-ide-141.2135290-windows.exe .

Installed fine, the brought up SDK dialog to install the missing SDK tools.  Wanted to know the android SDK location.  Clicked c:\android and it got really confused as it appended android-SDK onto the URL.  Which seemed correct.

I manually entered c:\android into the location to indicate only missing components would be updated, let it go, and it installed fine.

Ugly but hope it helps.  Healy in Tampa

Answer (score 0):

On windows 10 just turn off your internet connection and open the Android Studio again.

If that does not work right click on it (Android Studio shortcut), go to properties and set the compatibility to Windows 7 and run again while your internet is off.

Answer (score 0):

If you use native language in computer, Change it to English , it would be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Just **close your internet connection** and try again !! it work for me